# Freemarker - print an object into another object

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm currently working with the FreeMarker Java Template Engine (.ftl)

I have a config file object that i would like to print into another ftl file (OutputScript.ftl)

Here is my config.ftl

```
<#assign config = {
"hp": {
    "product" : {
        "title": {
            "top": "true",
            "bottom": "false"
        }
    }
}
} />
```

Here is my OutputScript.ftl

```
<script>
window.object = {
    config : {
        // write the config object inside
    }
}
</script>
```

I have set up a page (page.ftl) where I call both files

```
<#import "/config/config.ftl" as config />
<#attempt><#include "XXX/OutputScript.ftl" /><#recover><!--Error: module OutputScript.ftl ${.error}--></#attempt>
```

Currently, i'm not able to to print it out.
I have tried stuff like this without any luck

```
          <#if config.config.hp??>
            <#list config.config.hp as page>
                ${key}: ${page[key]}
            </#list>
        </#if>
```

Also, can we make it dynamic?(if my config file will have more indentation, will it still work?)

Thanks

Comment: Please always include the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated Freemarker to the last version in order to use the [?eval_json](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_eval_json)

```
<#assign config = '{
    "test" :"testValue",
    "hp": {
        "product" : {
            "title": {
                "top": {
                    "header": {
                        "big": "true",
                        "test" : 14
                    },
                    "header2": {
                        "big2": "true2"
                    },
                    "header3" : "true3"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'>

<#assign configRedux = config?eval_json>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print a map (a "hash") directly with `${}`, only a string, number, date/time or boolean. So if you want to generate JSON, you have to write macros that traverse and print the data structure recursively.

Comment: Do you have a link as an exemple? I need something that can loop through all first object + detect if the insite is an object or display it. if object loop again etc